# How to Get $project.version in Custom Gradle Plugin?

Tags: groovy, gradle

Within a custom gradle plugin the `project.version` seems to always be `unspecified`. Why and how to retrieve the `project.version` within a custom plugin (class)?

For Example:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: MyPlugin

version = "1.0.0"

println "In build file: $project.version" 

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  public void apply(Project project) {
    project.task('myTask') {
      println "In plugin: $project.version"
    }
  }
}
```

Prints out:

```
%> gradle -q myTask
  In plugin: unspecified
  In build file: 1.0.0
```

Besides the how I really would like to know the why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You set the property after you call `apply`

If you move

```
version = "1.0.0"
```

To before the line

```
apply plugin: MyPlugin
```

It should work

#### Edit

[Following Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13198744/6509), you can see that this works also:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: MyPlugin

version = "1.0.0"

println "In build file: $project.version" 

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  public void apply(Project project) {
    project.task('myTask') {
      project.gradle.projectsEvaluated { 
        println "In plugin: $project.version"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To delay the evaluation of `$project.version` until evaluation of the build is complete

Comment: Thanks. Works. Makes total sense.

Comment: @jonbros Peter Niederwieser has [posted a much better solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13198744/6509) to re-ordering your build script. Edited my answer to show an example of it.

Comment: It's better to add the task immediately (otherwise the build script won't be able to access it) and only defer the part of its configuration that requires access to `project.version`. `println` is an unfortunate example because it would usually be done in a task action (`doLast { ... }`), which is only evaluated at *execution time* and therefore doesn't suffer from configuration order problems.

Answer (score 7):

Dealing with evaluation order is *the* challenge when writing plugins, and it requires some knowledge and expertise to master.

Notice that in the build script, the plugin gets applied (and therefore executed!) before the version is set. This is the norm, and the plugin has to deal with it. Roughly speaking, whenever the plugin accesses a mutable property of the Gradle object model, it has to defer that access until the end of the *configuration phase*. (Until then, the value of the property can still change.)

Some of Gradle's APIs (lazy collections, methods accepting callbacks, etc.) provide special support for dealing with this problem. Other than that, you can wrap affected code in `project.gradle.projectsEvaluated { ... }`, or use the more sophisticated "convention mapping" technique.

The [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) and http://forums.gradle.org provide more information on these topics.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that really is a better solution and you are right about it being challenging.
`project.version` is supposed to be a reasonable default for an extension introduced within the plugin. But I found use for `projectsEvaluated` method and took care not to override the setting with the default, by checking if it equals `unspecified` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050052/getversion-in-custom-gradle-plugin-is-always-unspecified/29354968#29354968)

You can place this block after the projectEvaluated closure or afterTask closure.  I haven't tested just pure standalone, but it may work.

```
AppExtension android = (AppExtension) project.extensions.findByName("android")
String versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName
String versionCode = android.defaultConfig.versionCode
```