# getVersion() in custom Gradle plugin is always unspecified

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

> Related to
>   [How to Get $project.version in Custom Gradle Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198358/how-to-get-project-version-in-custom-gradle-plugin)

**Executive summary:**  getVersion() inside of custom gradle plugin returns "unspecified"

I have created a custom gradle plugin that applies some business logic to our Android Studio / Gradle builds.  This plugin is run every time we do a CI build.

I want the plugin to be able to print out its version, which is an entirely different version number from that of the Android application being built, during builds. (useful debugging information during CI builds)

The build.gradle for the plugin (that gets deployed to a maven repo as a jar):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.example.foo.gradle'
version = "0.0.12"

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
}



configurations {
    includeInJar
}

dependencies {
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}


jar {

}


uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        def deployPath = file(getProperty('aar.deployPath'))
        repository(url: "file://${deployPath.absolutePath}")
        pom.project {
            groupId project.group
            artifactId 'foo-gradle-jenkins'
            version project.version
        }
    }
}
```

... and the plugin is applied to an Android app like this (sensitive parts omitted):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {   url "../../../plugin_builds" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.example.foo.gradle:foo-gradle-jenkins:0.0.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'foo'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.examplegradleapplication3"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

In the plugin I attempt to print its version like this:

```
@Override
    void apply(Project project) { 

        project.configure(project) {
            if (it.hasProperty("android")) {

                if (isJenkinsBuild()) { 
                    log("Plugin version: " + getVersion()) 

                    // ...
                }

                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

.. but whenever I perform gradle build of the Android app it thinks getVersion() is unspecified.

What should I be doing instead to track the plugin version at the time of another gradle build using it as a plugin?

Comment: `getVersion()` obtains the version of the *currently executing* Gradle build, not the build that was used to create the plugin Jar.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth how can you get the version of the build that was used to create the plugin Jar?

Answer (score 2):

```
AppExtension android = (AppExtension) project.extensions.findByName("android")
String versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName
String versionCode = android.defaultConfig.versionCode
```

Answer (score 1):

`project.configure(project) { println getVersion() }` is the same as `println project.version`. If this prints `unspecified`, the build script didn't set `(project.)version`.

As of Gradle 2.2, there isn't a built-in way for a plugin to declare or query its own version, but you could implement this yourself (for your own plugins).

Comment: Thanks Peter, any suggestions on how I could track and query the plugin version?  Maybe as part of the JAR itself?

Comment: You could add a properties file to the plugin Jar, or hardcode the version in a `MyPlugin#getVersion` method.

Comment: What about the manifest?  There's even an API for reading it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html.

Comment: Manifest works as well. That may be a bit harder to implement than having your own properties file though.